# Is it possible that there isn't a linear span which precisely spans a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, span

In the assignment I'm asked to decide whether given:

$S = \Bigg \{ \begin{bmatrix}a &b \\ c &d\end{bmatrix} \in M_2(\mathbb{R}) \; | \; ad = 0 \Bigg \},\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R}$.

$S$ is a vector space.  I believe that addition and multiplication by scalar are defined point-wise.  I believe that this is a vector space, but the question also asks to construct a linear span of this space (provided it is a space).  And here I'm in doubt: any two matrices with $a$ or $d$ non-zero would create elements not in $S$, but if I leave out either $a$ or $d$, the span won't generate every possible matrix.  Is this an okay situation, or did I do something wrong?

Comment: $S$ is not a vector space..

Comment: @PeterFranek that would certainly explain the problem, but just in general, is it possible that there is no span that precisely spans a vector space, or if I can't find one, it means that what I assumed to be a vector space isn't one?

Comment: I'm not sure if I uderstand the question. The span of any vector space is this vector space itself, and any vector space is spanned by its basis (or by itself, if you want). The span of some set that is *not* a vector space is something larger. In your case, the span of $S$ is all of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @PeterFranek even though you don't understand it, you answered it... well, good enough for me! :)

Answer (score 10):

**Theorem**: every vector space has a [basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_%28linear_algebra%29) (and any two bases of the vector space have the same cardinality).

This theorem is the cornerstone of linear algebra, and usually the case of finite-dimensional vector spaces is proven in a linear algebra class. (I should warn that the above isn't true in general unless you assume the axiom of choice.)

Your specific set is *not* a vector space: $\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0 \end{array} \right) \in S$ and $\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0\\
0 & 1 \end{array} \right)\in S$, but their sum, $\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1 \end{array} \right) \not\in S$.

Comment: Pedantry: AoC for infinite-dimensional vector spaces

Comment: @par See the second paragraph ;)

Comment: Nice. My bad :>

Comment: @par One usually works in ZFC, do you also point out when people use the excluded middle?

Comment: Are there any good references on infinite-dimensional vector spaces which shows how this theorem applies using the AoC?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm learning by the book "Fundamentals of Linear Algebra" by James B. Carrell which doesn't say that the vector space must be closed under addition. But it says that the addition must be commutative and associative. Now I wonder: does it suffice to say that addition is commutative and associative to claim closure, or is there something missing in the definition?

Comment: @wvxvw To *define* an addition on a vector space means that it's closed under addition (recall that addition is a map $V \times V \to V$ - so that, by definition of the addition map, $v+w \in V$.

Comment: @user2345215: Some type theorists point out LEM. But yes, point taken :>

Answer (score 2):

Since we're considering $S \subset \Bbb M_2(\Bbb R)$, it is natural to assume that the operations on $S$ are inherited from $\Bbb M_2(\Bbb R)$. But $S$ as it is, is **not** a subspace of $\Bbb M_2(\Bbb R)$. We have that $$\begin{bmatrix} a_1 & b_1 \\ c_1 & d_1\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} a_2 & b_2 \\ c_2 & d_2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a_1+a_2 & b_1+b_2 \\ c_1+c_2 & d_1+d_2\end{bmatrix}$$

If $a_1=d_2 = 0$ but $a_2,d_1 \neq 0$, closure under addition fails. But $${\rm span} \ S = \bigcap_{S \subset W \leq V} W$$ is always a vector space (intersection of vector spaces is still one). Now, finding a basis for ${\rm span} \ S$ is another problem.